# Getting the values from a cell of Excell file is not working

Tags: java, excel

I am using the following code that i read on " http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator "   under the heading "Getting the cell contents". It's giving so many errors even before compiling. I am mentioning the errors at the end.What I want to do is to take the content of a cell of the excel sheet and compare its value with the contents of a field in my web app, which has the ID lets say "label22"

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;



public class ReadCell {
public static void main(String[] args) {
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("D:\\rptViewer.xls");
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(inp));
ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);

extractor.setFormulasNotResults(true);
extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(false);
String text = extractor.getText();



/*
* Read excel file using j excel file
*/

Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
for (Row row : sheet1) {
for (Cell cell : row) {
    CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
    System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
    System.out.print(" - ");

    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            }
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Errors are:

```
getColumnIndex : The method getColumnIndex() is undefined for the type Cell
wb.getSheetAt(0): Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFSheet to Sheet
formatAsString()); :  The method formatAsString() is undefined for the type CellReference
getCellType()) {  :The method getCellType() is undefined for the type Cell
getRichStringCellValue()  : The method getRichStringCellValue() is undefined for the type Cell
CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:    :  CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Comment: why are you using both POI and JXL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is wrong. use:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
```

instead of:

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
```

Comment: After importing the above, there are  only two errors left at :
`formatAsString());`  : The method formatAsString() is undefined for the type CellReference

Comment: and the other at : `wb.getSheetAt(0);` 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFSheet to Sheet

Comment: Take a look at POI javadoc. See the class names, methods and return types. This way you can fix all your errors by yourself and even learn something from it...

Answer (score 1):

[JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) (now 'JExcel') and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) are two separate excel apis available to java developers for interfacing with microsoft excel.

you can surely not expect these two to be compatible with each other, that is why you are getting the type mismatch errors.

(you should use only POI or only JXL)
for POI you can import

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
```

and change your code to

```
HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problems change case to :

```
  switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case FORMULA:
                System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println();
            }
```